# How to add IAM Condition access using Google Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I was trying to setup for GCS bucket using deployment manager template but cannot find how to setup condition.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-toolkit/blob/master/dm/templates/gcs_bucket/gcs_bucket.py

Comment: Have you seen the example in the directory/namespace?
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-toolkit/blob/master/dm/templates/gcs_bucket/examples/gcs_bucket_iam_bindings.yaml#L31-L35

Comment: Does adding the `accessControl` helped?

Answer (score 0):

As advised by Tanjin the code snippet is already included in the namespace you have shared.

You will also need to add the `accessControl` section to the top-level configuration for each resource for which you want to apply access control policies.

Here is the code sample:

```
resources:
- name: a-new-pubsub-topic
  type: pubsub.v1.topic
  properties:
    ...

  accessControl:
    gcpIamPolicy:
      bindings:
      - role: roles/pubsub.editor
        members:
        - "user:alice@example.com"
      - role: roles/pubsub.publisher
        members:
        - "user:jane@example.com"
        - "serviceAccount:my-other-app@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
```

You can also check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/set-access-control-resources#setting_an_iam_policy_in_your_configuration) for the official GCP guide on that setup.